# Polynomial With Prime Powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Prove that for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $   a^{pq} - a^{p} - a^{q} + a \equiv 0 \pmod{pq}. $

I have tried using variations of Fermats Little theorem but have made little headway

Comment: You only need $a^p\equiv a\mod p$ for every prime $p$ and every ineteger $a$ (See the answer below)

Comment: Please do not delete the body of your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$a^{pq}=(a^q)^p\equiv a^q\mod p$$ and $$a^p\equiv a\mod p$$

This implies $$a^{pq}-a^p-a^q+a\equiv 0\mod p$$

For $q$, the proof can be made completely analogue.